# Play mp3 files continuously in Recycler View Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have **RecyclerView** with **mp3 files**.
I want to play mp3 files **continuously** started **from clicked item. Like playing song track**

How can I handle?

Following method is for one item click

```
@OnClick(R.id.audioContentLayout)
public void onClick(View view) {
    nextPlayList = messageViewModel.getAudioMessagePlayList(((ConversationMessageAdapter) adapter).getMessages(), message);
    playAudioMessage(message);
}
```

To play continuously, I try in onBind() method of ViewHolder class. But it **can't** play mp3 file continuously.

```
@Override
public void onBind(UiMessage message) {
....
if (message.isPlaying) {
        animation = (AnimationDrawable) ivAudio.getBackground();
        if (!animation.isRunning()) {
            animation.start();
        }
    } else {
          if(nextPlayList.size() > 0){
            onBind(nextPlayList.get(0), getAdapterPosition()+1);
            playAudioMessage(nextPlayList.get(0));
        }
       }
```

Here is playAudioMessage() method

```
private void playAudioMessage(UiMessage uiMessage) {
        File file = messageViewModel.mediaMessageContentFile(uiMessage);
        if (file == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (file.exists()) {
            messageViewModel.playAudioMessage(uiMessage);
        } else {
            if (uiMessage.isDownloading) {
                return;
            }
            messageViewModel.downloadMedia(uiMessage, file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: inside playAudioMessage(..) method, just set  mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

Comment: I want to play next mp3 file from clicked item in Recycler view.

Comment: then modify your question and state properly, provide an appropriate code snippet of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I add some code that I tried. Please help me to give some suggestion. Thanks ^^)

Comment: for playing continuously, check your media playing logic, post your code for playAudioMessage() method.